# filtered data are shown one tempo late in React

Tags: reactjs, filter

I wrote in the code what's problem here.
so When I clicked filter, it doesn't show filtered data. (just same data are there)
but when I click again, it shows previously filtered data
so it's one tempo late..
Like I wrote,

```js
const filterValue = state[filterBy];
```

I think this part is the reason of this problem. 
If I click, the `filterValue` should have `state[filterBy]` value.
but it's not with the same reason with above..
How could I make it work syncronously?

```js
//it's onClick event. So when I click dropdown filter, it recieves object key(label), and value(option)

function filterItems(label, option) {
    switch (label) {
      case 'isFinished':
        setFilter({ ...filter, isFinished: option });
        break;
      case 'state':
        setFilter({ ...filter, state: option });
        break;
      default:
        break;
    }

    const state = filter;
    ['isFinished', 'state'].forEach((filterBy) => {
      const filterValue = state[filterBy];
      if (filterValue) {
        copyInfo = copyInfo.filter((item) => {
          return (
            item['isFinished'] === filterValue || item['state'] === filterValue
          );
        });
      }
    });

    setFilteredInfo([...copyInfo]);
  }
```

- Edited
  The reason why it worked one tempo late was
  `setState` function works asynchronously.
  In the code above, I did `setFilter`, and right after that
  I used `filter` state expecting it would already be updated.
  But the state is not updated before component is re-rendered.
  That means you can't use updated state before component re-rendered.
  To solve this, you can use `ref` instead of `state`.

Comment: add sample code in codesandbox for debug

Comment: oh it was not about `const filterValue = state[filterBy];`

Comment: it was because `setFilter` method. setFilter method is not working in syncronously. so I couldn't get the right data right away..